# Convert recursive function into the non-recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

Is it possible to convert the function `go` into the non-recursive function? Some hints or a start-up sketch would be very helpful

```
public static TSPSolution solve(CostMatrix _cm, TSPPoint start, TSPPoint[] points, long seed) {
    TSPSolution sol = TSPSolution.randomSolution(start, points, seed, _cm);
    double t = initialTemperature(sol, 1000);
    int frozen = 0;
    System.out.println("-- Simulated annealing started with initial temperature " + t + " --");
    return go(_cm, sol, t, frozen);
}

private static TSPSolution go(CostMatrix _cm, TSPSolution solution, double t, int frozen) {
    if (frozen >= 3) {
        return solution;
    }
    i++;

    TSPSolution bestSol = solution;
    System.out.println(i + ": " + solution.fitness() + " " + solution.time() + " "
            + solution.penalty() + " " + t);
    ArrayList<TSPSolution> nHood = solution.nHood();

    int attempts = 0;
    int accepted = 0;

    while (!(attempts == 2 * nHood.size() || accepted == nHood.size()) && attempts < 500) {
        TSPSolution sol = nHood.get(rand.nextInt(nHood.size()));
        attempts++;

        double deltaF = sol.fitness() - bestSol.fitness();
        if (deltaF < 0 || Math.exp(-deltaF / t) > Math.random()) {
            accepted++;
            bestSol = sol;
            nHood = sol.nHood();
        }
    }

    frozen = accepted == 0 ? frozen + 1 : 0;

    double newT = coolingSchedule(t);

    return go(_cm, bestSol, newT, frozen);

}
```

Comment: Yes. All recursive methods can be non recursive methods and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an easy one, because it is tail-recursive: there is no code between the recursive call & what the function returns.  Thus, you can wrap the body of `go` in a loop `while (frozen<3)`, and `return solution` once the loop ends.  And replace the recursive call with assignments to the parameters: `solution=bestSol; t=newT;`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to thinkg about two things:

1. What changes on each step?
2. When does the algorithm end?

Ans the answer should be

1. `bestSol` (`solution`), `newT` (`t`), `frozen` (`frozen`)
2. When `frozen >= 3` is true

So, the easiest way is just to enclose the whole function in something like

```
while (frozen < 3) {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    frozen = accepted == 0 ? frozen + 1 : 0;
    //double newT = coolingSchedule(t);
    t = coolingSchedule(t);
    solution = bestSol;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, the simplest way to make a recursive function iterative is to load the first element onto a Stack, and instead of calling the recursion, add the result to the Stack.

For instance:

```
public Item recursive(Item myItem)
{
    if(myItem.GetExitCondition().IsMet()
    {
        return myItem;
    }
    ... do stuff ...
    return recursive(myItem);
}
```

Would become:

```
public Item iterative(Item myItem)
{
    Stack<Item> workStack = new Stack<>();
    while (!workStack.isEmpty())
    {
        Item workItem = workStack.pop()
        if(myItem.GetExitCondition().IsMet()
        {
            return workItem;
        }
        ... do stuff ...
        workStack.put(workItem)
    }
    // No solution was found (!).
    return myItem;
}
```

This code is untested and may (read: does) contain errors. It may not even compile, but should give you a general idea.