# Convert recursive function to for and while loop [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, recursion, while-loop

I have the functions:

```
h(0) = 0
h(1) = 3
h(n) = h(n-1) + 2 * h(n-2), for n>= 2
```

I need to convert this into a for loop, while loop, and recursive function. I have the recursive function figured out, but I can't seem to output the correct answer. My attempt at the for loop is this:

```
def hForLoop(n):
    sum = 3
    for i in range(2, n):
        sum = sum + ((i - 1) + 2 * (i - 2))
    return sum
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm outputting the wrong answer. Some insight would be very useful and I will be very grateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert recursive function into the non-recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998550/convert-recursive-function-into-the-non-recursive-function)

Comment: I disagree one is java the OP is writing in python

Comment: It might help if you explained exactly what is happening, instead of vaguely saying that there is an "issue".  Does the code not run at all?  Does it throw an exception?  Does it produce incorrect results, and if so, how do the results differ from what you expected?

Comment: @cowbert The first isn't java, it's a system of functions. My task is to write those system of functions in Python.

Comment: SamGoodin that was for @StarShine, they linked to an answer in Java

Comment: I ws under the impression that the language was not the issue, but the technique to convert recursive functions into iterative code was what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the version that stores just the last two values in a series:

```
def hForLoop(n):
    prev, cur = 0, 3
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        cur, prev = cur + prev * 2, cur
    return cur
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in you for-loop, where you increment `sum` with `((i - 1) + 2 * (i - 2))`.
If you understood the original functions, it should really be increment `sum` with the previously computed value stored at `h(i-1)` and `h(i-2)`.

Here's my fix to your for-loop function:

```
def hForLoop(n):
    sum = [0,3]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        sum.append((sum[i - 1]) + 2 * (sum[i - 2]))
    return sum[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the intermediate values for `h(n-1)` and `h(n-2)` for the next iteration of the loop, where you use the values to calculate the next `h(n)`.

```
 def hLoop(n):

   # initally [h(2), h(1), h(0)]
   h = [3, 3, 0] 

   # And in the following: [ h(i), h(i-1), h(i-2)]
   for i in range(2,  n + 1):
      # calculate h(i)
      h[0] = h[1] + 2 * h[2]
      # move 'index' forward, h(n-1) becomes h(n-2), h(n-1) becomes h(n-0)
      h[2] = h[1]
      h[1] = h[0]

   return h[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

With original function:

```
h(0) = 0
h(1) = 3
h(n) = h(n-1) + 2 * h(n-2), for n>= 2
```

you actual code is:

```
h(0) = 0
h(1) = 3
h(n) = Σ((n-1) + 2 * (n-2)), for n>= 2
```

See the difference?